# ¿Como puedo hacer para escribir codigo html en python

Tags: python, django

estaba teniedo una duda acerca de si como escribir codigo html en python ya que cuando lo quiro pasar no puedo

```
{% extends 'encyclopedia/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}
{% endblock  %}

{% block body %}

    {{ lines }}

    <form action="{% url 'wiki:edit' title %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ search }}">
        
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Text">
    </form>
{% endblock  %}
```

En la variable lines tengo codigo html pero cuando voy al codigo fuente de mi pagina ocurre esto:

```
     &lt;h1&gt;Python&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h1&gt;Python&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h1&gt;PythonPython is a programming language that can be used both for writing &lt;strong&gt;command-line scripts&lt;/strong&gt; or building &lt;strong&gt;web applications&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

¿Como puedo pasar el codigo sin que ocurra esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para codigo HTML directo (con tags incluidos) debes usar el filtro `safe`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

```
{{ lines|safe }}
```

Esto es para evitar [*cross-scripting*](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) o cualquier problema con entrada de usuario insegura que puede romper la estructura de la pagina. Solo debes usar `safe` en contenido HTML que sabes que es seguro de mostrar (generado por ti) de otro modo pueden ocurrir efectos inesperados con contenido inseguro.